# In what way can I produce a list of DFMs used in a project?

Tags: delphi, linker

I want to make a Delphi plug-in that can list all the DFMs in the current project.

Is there a way to get a list of all DFM files (and their paths) linked in the current project?

If all the DFMs are listed, then things can be extracted about the project, and maybe do searches only on the current project DFMs, like parsing the DFMs to find a property.

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280552/), which was answered, but doesn't address how to get to the DFMs.  And that solution requires changing every `.pas` file in the Repository, and gives a solution at run-time.  My question is about design-time.

Comment: You say plug-in, so I'm assuming you want to find the forms at design-time? Please clarify..

Comment: IDE addons are implemented using the [OpenTools API](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Extending_the_IDE_Using_the_Tools_API), which has interfaces available for enumerating the project settings, forms, associated files (`.pas`, `.dfm`), etc.  Look at the `ToolsAPI` and related units, and at the `IOTAProjectGroup`, `IOTAProject`  and `IOTAModule` interfaces (just to name a few), and the `GetActiveProject()` standalone function. There are plenty of OpenTools tutorials floating around if you look around.

Comment: Yes, i want to find the forms at design time. Yes i am using IOTA. however i just found how to create a project, i could not find a tutorial on how to iterate over data.

Comment: http://www.davidghoyle.co.uk/WordPress/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/The-Delphi-IDE-Open-Tools-API-Version-1.1.pdf a book on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick example using OpenTools API. Add this unit to a new design-only package, add `designide` and `vcl` to the `requires` clause. Compile and install the package. It will add a menu item 'List DFM' under Help\Help Wizards. Clicking it will invoke the `Execute` method below.

```
unit ListDfmExample;

interface

uses
  Windows, VCL.Forms, VCL.Dialogs, Classes, SysUtils, ToolsAPI;

type
  TListDfmWizard = class(TNotifierObject, IOTAWizard, IOTAMenuWizard)
    { IOTAWizard }
    function GetIDString: string;
    function GetName: string;
    function GetState: TWizardState;
    procedure Execute;
    { IOTAMenuWizard }
    function GetMenuText: string;
  end;

implementation

function TListDfmWizard.GetIDString: string;
begin
  Result := 'TOndrej.ListDfmWizard';
end;

function TListDfmWizard.GetName: string;
begin
  Result := 'ListDfm';
end;

function TListDfmWizard.GetState: TWizardState;
begin
  Result := [wsEnabled];
end;

procedure TListDfmWizard.Execute;
var
  Project: IOTAProject;
  I, J: Integer;
  ModuleInfo: IOTAModuleInfo;
  Module: IOTAModule;
  Editor: IOTAEditor;
  FormEditor: IOTAFormEditor;
  List: TStringList;
begin
  Project := GetActiveProject;
  if not Assigned(Project) then
    Exit;

  List := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for I := 0 to Project.GetModuleCount - 1 do
    begin
      ModuleInfo := Project.GetModule(I);
      if ModuleInfo.FormName <> '' then
      begin
        Module := ModuleInfo.OpenModule;
        for J := 0 to Module.ModuleFileCount - 1 do
        begin
          Editor := Module.ModuleFileEditors[J];
          if Supports(Editor, IOTAFormEditor, FormEditor) then
            List.Add(FormEditor.FileName);
        end;
      end;
    end;

    ShowMessage(List.Text);
  finally
    List.Free;
  end;
end;

function TListDfmWizard.GetMenuText: string;
begin
  Result := 'List DFM';
end;

initialization
  RegisterPackageWizard(TListDfmWizard.Create);

end.
```

Comment: This code works only on small scale projects. a project with more then 100 forms , it could break with error "error creating form system error code 1158" Is there something missing?